# Submission of PHP Form to XAMPP MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I created a php form for a catering service that I'm planning to insert into a MySQL database: The php form is called index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>BOOTSTRAP</title>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="inquiry col-md-6">
        <h1>Inquire Now</h1>
            <form method="post" action="inquire.php" name="inquireform" id="inquireForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Name*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="Cust`Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputLocation">Location*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputLocation" placeholder="Location" name="Location">
                </div>
            </form>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="SelectDate">Date of Event*</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectMonth" name="Month">
                        <option>Jan</option>
                        <option>Feb</option>
                        <option>Mar</option>
                        <option>Apr</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>Jun</option>
                        <option>Jul</option>
                        <option>Aug</option>
                        <option>Sept</option>
                        <option>Oct</option>
                        <option>Nov</option>
                        <option>Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDay" name="Day">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>18</option>
                        <option>19</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>21</option>
                        <option>22</option>
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>24</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>26</option>
                        <option>27</option>
                        <option>28</option>
                        <option>29</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectYear" placeholder="Year" name="Year">
                        <option>2017</option>
                        <option>2018</option>
                        <option>2019</option>
                        <option>2020</option>
                        <option>2021</option>
                        <option>2022</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                </form>
                <form>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputNumber">Number of Guests*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="Number" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Number" name="Guests">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputContact">Contact Number*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputContact" placeholder="Contact Number" name="ContNum">
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the inquire.php is:

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "catering";

$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inquiry`(`CustName`,`Location`,`Month`,`Day`,`Year`,`Guests`,`ContNum`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("sssssss", print_r($POST)['CustName'], print_r($POST)['Location'], print_r($POST)['Month'], print_r($POST)['Day'], print_r($POST)['Year'], print_r($POST)['Guests'], print_r($POST)['ContNum']);
$prepare->execute();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Which I got from this other question: [How to write information from html form to MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604878/how-to-write-information-from-html-form-to-mysql-database)

However, mine doesn't work. The php url just changes, no data is inserted into my database. I'm thinking maybe something's wrong with my setup or installation maybe its one of the following?

1. I have no PHP installed in my PC, just XAMPP.
2. I put the index.php and inquire.php in a folder in xampp >htdocs
3. I run XAMPP in Admin mode.
4. the print_r($_POST) might be incorrect.

Guys i really need help. I made sure the database name, table name, and column names matched. What could I be doing wrong here?

DATABASE PIC: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNZA9.png)

Update ;

> No data still inserted, the url only changes from file://index.php to
>   file://index.php?Guests=2&ContNum=123

Comment: UPDATE: Change the columns to the right data type on database. Still no data inserted.

Comment: Do u know what does print_r do?

Comment: Yes, why `print_r($_POST)['...']` and not `$_POST['...']` ?

And try to check for errors after each step, that way you know which part of your code is working and which not.

Link: http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin I used $_POST['...'] before but it did not add info to database, In the link, I saw a user said please use print_r($_POST) then the guy who asked the question said it worked. Ima try i again.

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST)` before adding to db, to see if you receive all parameters.
And, now that i take a closer look, why do you have nested forms? You should have just one.

Comment: The problem is that you not running php from a server but from a browser directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run php files on my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580273/how-to-run-php-files-on-my-computer)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have xampp running and Apache and MySQL installed and started

Comment: you need to type on your browser this : localhost/FolderThatUssavdthefileon

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin for the nested form I'm using bootstrap. for the date form, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/tXYiu

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried it, localhost/form/index.php is the url, pictures got removed? When i clicked submit, the url still change to http://localhost/form/index.php?Guests=2&ContNum=201 still it didnot insert the data i submitted to the database

Answer (score 1):

Use localhost/your_project_name.html to access your project in the URL bar. Basically you don't use "xampp localhost" you just double-click on the html file from what i get.

Ok there are some MORE problems with the code that I spotted.

First of all inside the `print_r($POST['something'])` in your query change it to `$_POST['something']`. Moving forward you have wrong values inside post for example `$_POST['Cust Name']` in your form is set name="Cust`Name". Then you have too many forms you must narrow it down. For 1 html file you can't have that many form. Php can not "read elements" it's server side so if you keep that structure maybe you should consider ajax call to php.

```
<form method="post" action="inquire.php" name="inquireform" id="inquireForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputName">Name*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="Cust`Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="InputLocation">Location*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputLocation" placeholder="Location" name="Location">
    </div>
</form>
```

This part here will make the request to php file but that's it the rest will not be send through request because they are included in another form , without action and php file is not included there.

Comment: Yes i already changed it to localhost/form/index.html, it removed my inage slider, logo, menu images and still didnt submit the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is most likely to be incorrect, you could remove the `print_r` and it should be `$_POST` not `$POST`. I'm assuming that the POST names are correct, and are supplied. To be safe, change `Mysqli` to `mysqli`

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "catering";

$mysqli  = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inquiry`(`CustName`,`Location`,`Month`,`Day`,`Year`,`Guests`,`ContNum`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("sssssss", $_POST['CustName'], $_POST['Location'], $_POST['Month'], $_POST['Day'], $_POST['Year'], $_POST['Guests'], $_POST['ContNum']);
$prepare->execute();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

This would be better if you first put the data in a variable

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "catering";

$custName = $_POST['CustName'];
$location= $_POST['Location'];
$month= $_POST['Month'];
$day= $_POST['Day'];
$year= $_POST['Year'];
$guests= $_POST['Guests'];
$contNum= $_POST['ContNum'];

$mysqli  = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inquiry`(`CustName`,`Location`,`Month`,`Day`,`Year`,`Guests`,`ContNum`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("sssssss",
                    $custName,
                    $location,
                    $month,
                    $day,
                    $year,
                    $guests,
                    $contNum);
$prepare->execute();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: removed the prints still nothing. The url only changes from file://index.php to file://index.php?Guests=2&ContNum=123 When i input "2" into guests and "123" in contact number.

Comment: I just noticed that you have multiple `<form>`, just use one for the whole form

Comment: @Swellar look at the url that means he;'s not using a web server to run the script

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I don't really know what it looks like when it is run without a server, so I thought OP uses GET instead of POST. Now that you said it, it is `file://` instead of `localhost`

Comment: @Swellar the moment is `file://` that means its not running under webserver

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I changed it to localhost/form/index.php, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
$prepare->bind_param("sssssss", print_r($POST)['CustName'], print_r($POST)['Location'], print_r($POST)['Month'], print_r($POST)['Day'], print_r($POST)['Year'], print_r($POST)['Guests'], print_r($POST)['ContNum']);
```

To this :

```
$prepare->bind_param("sssssss", $_POST['CustName'], $_POST['Location'], $_POST['Month'], $_POST['Day'], $_POST['Year'], $_POST['Guests'], $_POST['ContNum']);
```

NB : Is also important to validate user input before storing

Comment: no data still inserted, the url only changes from file://index.php to file://index.php?Guests=2&ContNum=123

Comment: you are not running php from a server that is why @GorilyaWarfare

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580273/how-to-run-php-files-on-my-computer

Comment: I run it on localhost bruh and its still not working

Comment: is your page .html or .php? @GorilyaWarfare

Answer (score 0):

You have more forms in the html, you need to have just one. I commented out the extra ones so you can understand better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>BOOTSTRAP</title>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="inquiry col-md-6">
        <h1>Inquire Now</h1>
            <form method="post" action="inquire.php" name="inquireform" id="inquireForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Name*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="Cust`Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputLocation">Location*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputLocation" placeholder="Location" name="Location">
                </div>
            <!-- </form> -->
            <!-- <form class="form-inline"> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="SelectDate">Date of Event*</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectMonth" name="Month">
                        <option>Jan</option>
                        <option>Feb</option>
                        <option>Mar</option>
                        <option>Apr</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>Jun</option>
                        <option>Jul</option>
                        <option>Aug</option>
                        <option>Sept</option>
                        <option>Oct</option>
                        <option>Nov</option>
                        <option>Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDay" name="Day">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>18</option>
                        <option>19</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>21</option>
                        <option>22</option>
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>24</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>26</option>
                        <option>27</option>
                        <option>28</option>
                        <option>29</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectYear" placeholder="Year" name="Year">
                        <option>2017</option>
                        <option>2018</option>
                        <option>2019</option>
                        <option>2020</option>
                        <option>2021</option>
                        <option>2022</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!-- </form> -->
                <!-- <form> -->
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputNumber">Number of Guests*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="Number" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Number" name="Guests">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputContact">Contact Number*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputContact" placeholder="Contact Number" name="ContNum">
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```