# Inserted PHP Form to MySQL Database produces duplicate with unexpected results

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Hi I searched for another method of inserting records from php form to xampp. I come across this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXcp7IYi41Q

I combined all the answers from my last question and changed my code to this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>BOOTSTRAP</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inquiry col-md-6">
        <h1>Inquire Now</h1>
            <form method="post" action="insert.php" id="frmBox" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Name*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="CustName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputLocation">Location*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputLocation" placeholder="Location" name="Location">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="SelectDate">Date of Event*</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectMonth" name="Month">
                        <option>Jan</option>
                        <option>Feb</option>
                        <option>Mar</option>
                        <option>Apr</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>Jun</option>
                        <option>Jul</option>
                        <option>Aug</option>
                        <option>Sept</option>
                        <option>Oct</option>
                        <option>Nov</option>
                        <option>Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDay" name="Day">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>18</option>
                        <option>19</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>21</option>
                        <option>22</option>
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>24</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>26</option>
                        <option>27</option>
                        <option>28</option>
                        <option>29</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectYear" placeholder="Year" name="Year">
                        <option>2017</option>
                        <option>2018</option>
                        <option>2019</option>
                        <option>2020</option>
                        <option>2021</option>
                        <option>2022</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputNumber">Number of Guests*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="Number" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Number" name="Guests">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="InputContact">Contact Number*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputContact" placeholder="Contact Number" name="ContactNum">
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!--SCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'insert.php',
                data:$('#frmBox').serialize(),
                success:function(response){
                    $('#success').html(response);
                }
            });
            var form=document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This one for the insert.php

```
?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $dbpassword="";
    $dbname="catering";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$dbpassword,$dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Could Not Connect:".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
        $CustName=test_input($_POST['CustName']);
        $Location=test_input($_POST['Location']);
        $Month=test_input($_POST['Month']);
        $Day=test_input($_POST['Day']);
        $Year=test_input($_POST['Year']);
        $Guests=test_input($_POST['Guests']);
        $ContactNum=test_input($_POST['ContactNum']);

        $sql="INSERT INTO inquiry(CustName,Location,Month,Day,Year,Guests,ContactNum)VALUES('$CustName','$Location','$Month','$Day','$Year','$Guests','$ContactNum')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            echo "Thank you for Inquiring";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failed to Inquire. Please try again";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    function test_input($data){
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=stripslashes($data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    }
?>
```

Now it's better than my previous code, I ran it on localhost, when i submit my test info, like Name, Location, Month, Day, Year, Guests and Contact Number, then I clicked submit right? The url does not change anymore, meaning its successfully connected to the database. But when I get to mySQL database, it produced this results:

[PIC OF DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0AEH.png)
As you guys can see, its all zeroes and it only appeared in Guests and ContactNum. First attempt at submitting, I got two results, then i tried it again many times. All zeroes and only appears on two columns. What do you guys think could be the problem here? Could it be a server error, setup error, installation error? Or a declaration error? Mismatch of names? What could i be missing? Please help. Thank you.

Heres my previous question for reference:  [Submission of PHP Form to XAMPP MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485057/submission-of-php-form-to-xampp-mysql-database/46486046#46486046)

Comment: you are submitting empty values  .. and seems you have not an autoincement column in your inqiry table

Comment: @scaisEdge what do you mean by submitting empty values? What do I need to change or modify in my code? In my database? What do I have to do? Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: seems that you  call the insert.php  but you have not proper value for  $_POST  ..be sure you have the correct content in $_POST for your index entry.

Comment: @scaisEdge  i checked my $_POST and all of the values are correct

Comment: @scaisEdge is it the id? Do I have to change their ids to match the ones in $_POST?

Comment: if all the values in $_POST are correct then check for the result of test_input(... )

Comment: @scaisEdge How do I actually check the result? Where do I go? What do I change?

Comment: try using  var_dump(test_input($_POST['CustName']));

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this. I just changed the table names:

```
CustName > customer_name
Location > customer_location
Month > date_month
Day > date_day
Year > date_year
Guests > number_guests
ContactNum > customer_contact
```